# validate accordion form section with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate, accordion

My form is set up as an accordion. I want to validate each section instead of the total form on submit. I can't get this to work.

A bit of my form (I left the hidden fields out):

```
<form id="test">
<div id="accordion">
<h3 class="frm_pos_top"><a href="#">Header</a></h3>
<div>
<div id="frm_field_179_container" class="frm_form_field form-field
frm_required_field form-group frm_top_container frm_first frm_half">
<label for="field_lz5ptt" class="frm_primary_label control-label">Question1
<span class="frm_required">*</span>
</label>
<select name="item_meta[179]" id="field_lz5ptt"  data-frmval="(Blanco)"
class="form-control"  >
<option value="(Blanco)"  selected="selected"> </option>
        <option value="10" >1</option>
        <option value="11" >2</option>
        <option value="12" >3</option>
        <option value="13" >4</option>
        <option value="20" >5</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="frm_field_86_container" class="frm_form_field form-field
frm_required_field form-group frm_top_container frm_half">
<label for="field_n9ta9n" class="frm_primary_label control-label">Question 2?
<span class="frm_required">*</span>
</label>
<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">€</span> <input
type="tel" id="field_n9ta9n" name="item_meta[86]" value=""  maxlength="6"
class="add_thou form-control"  />
</div>
</div>
<div class="back_next" style="float:right;"><input type="button" value="Volgende" id="button1" class="x-btn x-btn-flat x-btn-rounded x-btn-small volgende-button"/></div>
```

And my JS to validate:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var a = "item_meta[179]";
var b = "item_meta[86]";
var c = $("input[name='item_meta[83]']:checked").val();
$("#button1").on('click', function (){
var form = $("#test");
form.validate({
errorElement: 'span',
errorClass: 'help-block',
highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
$(element).closest('.form-group').addClass ("has-error");
},
unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
$(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass ("has-error");
},
rules: {
    a: {
        required: true,
    },
    b: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 4,
    },
},
massages: {
    a: {
        required: "Field is required",
    },
    b: {
        required: "Field is required"
    },
}
});

if (form.valid() == true){
    if(c == '2') {
    $("#ui-id-1").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
    $("#ui-id-3").removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
    $("#accordion").accordion({
    active: 1
    });
    } else {
    $("#ui-id-1").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
    $("#ui-id-5").removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
    $("#accordion").accordion({
    active: 2
    });
    }
}
});
});
```

I can't figure out where I go wrong. I have read every tutorial, but not seeing it. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I don't see any form elements except for one `select`.  You can only validate `input`, `textarea` and `select` elements;  you **cannot** validate a `div`. Secondly, you're assigning rules to `a` and `b`... and again you have no `form` elements with `name="a"` or `name="b"`.

Comment: Also, the `.validate()` method is only used for initialization of the plugin and would not go inside of a `click` handler.

Comment: Hi Sparky, there is 1 select element and also an input element (<input
type="tel" id="field_n9ta9n" name="item_meta[86]" value=""  maxlength="6"
class="add_thou form-control"  />). In my JS I made var a = "item_meta[86]". So I would think that should work.

Comment: no, it should not.  Use the name in place of `a` within `.validate()`

Comment: Yep, you are absolutely right. Edit my question (only the name), and works like charm. The .validate inside the click handler is not a problem. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: `.validate()` inside the `click` handler may not be giving you a problem, but it certainly does not make any sense.   The `.validate()` method is only used for initializing the plugin **one** time... it gets called on page load and the `click` of the submit button is captured automatically by the plugin.  If the button is a `type="button"`, then you need a `click` handler that programmatically calls the `.valid()` method to test the form, while the `.validate()` method remains external to any click handlers.

Comment: I see your point and your totally right. Edit my question again. This should be it. Thanks again for your help. It really helped me understand how this works.

Comment: StackOverflow is a high quality Question/Answer site where the material is saved to help future readers.  1)  Please do not edit the OP to fix the root code problems; then there would no longer exist a question that needs to be answered.  2)  Please post the solution below as an answer and "accept" it by clicking the green checkmark.   This way, other people will know what the problem was and how you solved it without having to figure out these comments.   I'm rolling back the question so you can post the solution below.  Thank-you!

Comment: Fixed this with changing my JS to:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get this working with changing the JS to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("#button1").on('click', function (){
var c = $("input[name='item_meta[83]']:checked").val();
var form = $("#test");
if (form.valid() == true){
if(c == '2') {
    $("#ui-id-1").addClass("ui-state-disabled gereed");
    $("#ui-id-3").removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
    $("#accordion").accordion({
    active: 1
    });
} else {
    $("#ui-id-1").addClass("ui-state-disabled gereed");
    $("#ui-id-5").removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
    $("#accordion").accordion({
    active: 2
    });
}
}
});
});    

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var form = $("#test");
form.validate({
    rules: {
        "item_meta[179]": {
            required: true,
            min: 1
        },
        "item_meta[86]": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 4
        }
},
messages: {
"item_meta[179]": "Required",
"item_meta[86]": {
        required: "Required",
        minlength: "Minlength is 1.000"
        }
},
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
});
```